# React with yup error Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type. TS2538

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup, unform

I'm using yup to invalidate the forms, when they are invalidated I want this function to return the errors, but it always gives an error in validationErrors[error.path], it gets Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type

```
import { ValidationError } from 'yup';

interface Errors {
  [key: string]: string;
}

export default function getValidationErrors(err: ValidationError): Errors {
  const validationErrors: Errors = {};

  err.inner.forEach(error => {
    validationErrors[error.path] = error.message;
  });

  return validationErrors;
}


----------


Console error: 

    Type 'undefined' cannot be used as an index type.  TS2538
    11 |   err.inner.forEach((error) => {
  > 12 |     validationErrors[error.path] = error.message;
       |                      ^
    13 |   });
    14 |
    15 |   return validationErrors;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that `ValidationError`'s `path` field is [declared](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/b97c39d/src/ValidationError.ts) as optional:

```ts
export default class ValidationError extends Error {
  value: any;
  path?: string; // path?: string | undefined
  type?: string;
  errors: string[];

  params?: Params;

  inner: ValidationError[];
...
```

That means that even when it's present on the error object it's value can  (from typescript's point of view) be `undefined`.

So before using `error.path` as a computed index value you have to check that it's not `undefined`. You either check it as supposed:

```ts
  err.inner.forEach(error => {
    if (typeof error.path !== 'undefined') {
      validationErrors[error.path] = error.message;
    }
  });
```

Or if you're absolutely sure it may never be `undefined` you can just [type assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) it with [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) `!`:

```ts
  err.inner.forEach(error => {
    validationErrors[error.path!] = error.message;
  });
```

But keep in mind that with type assertion if your suggestion was wrong you'll get `validationErrors.undefined` field in your error object.